# Sort by 2 variables prioritizng 1

Tags: javascript, angular, sorting

I have a list of `posts`. These posts have a date (`created`) and a score (`score`). What I would like to do is sort them by `created` and `score` but having `score` as the more important variable..

In other words sort all posts in order of `created` but having the highest `score` show first..

So essentially:

```
score: 6, created: july 1 //created is actually a timestamp 1530372915676
score: 4, created: july 1
score: 2, created: july 1
score: 1, created: july 1
score: 5, created: june 30
score: 3, created: june 30
```

I found this piece of code:

```
array.sort(function (x, y) { return x.created - y.created || x.score - y.score; });
```

but it doesn't seem to work..

What would the best way of doing this be?

Comment: There seems to be a contradiction in your question. You say that `score` should be "the most important variable", but your example shows that the most important variable is `created`. Is the example the result that you get with your current code, or the result that you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could satisfy your requirement. It will first sort by `created` in `descending` order, and within each `created` item, it will sort by `score` in `descending(highest score first)`. Similar to sql query `order by created desc, score desc`

```
arr.sort(function (x, y) { 
       if(x.created != y.created) 
       { 
             return y.created - x.created 
       } 
       else return y.score-x.score
});
```

EDIT :
This should work too, without using `if`

```
arr.sort(function (x, y) { return y.created - x.created || y.score - x.score; });
```

Comment: Will the result be different from the original code?

Comment: OP is showing the example of the result they want. So this should work.

Comment: It should now work, yes. Why use the `if`? You could keep the `||` operator.

Answer (score 0):

Just swap `x` and `y` in the score comparison. It will make higher score go first in cases when the created date is the same:

```
array.sort(function (x, y) { return x.created - y.created || y.score - x.score; });
```